# Plot MSD (mean square displacement) versus time for a polymer chain

Tags: python, monte-carlo

[Cross-posted on Computational Science SE](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/43492/27325).

The following are the movements of the center of mass of a polymer chain over time in a monte carlo simulation.

```
#   cm-X     cm-Y    cm-Z
9.507 21.232 9.910
9.092 18.427 7.308
7.994 14.856 4.675
0.533 12.138 -1.163
-0.056 6.735 -5.470
-2.138 4.950 -7.280
0.736 13.076 -10.012
9.516 14.611 -12.470
0.886 17.235 -10.714
-8.954 21.381 -11.735
-7.457 16.042 -16.710
-0.842 13.984 -17.874
-2.799 13.195 -14.247
0.738 14.792 -11.774
5.760 9.218 -10.846
8.406 13.735 -15.946
6.848 12.679 -9.621
13.569 14.036 -6.348
8.665 12.724 -8.238
... ... ... ... ...
```

- [4.7.2.2. Mean Squared Displacement](https://docs.mdanalysis.org/2.0.0/documentation_pages/analysis/msd.html)

I want to draw a log-log plot of MSD (mean square displacement) versus `t` of a movement of the polymer chain to examine the diffusion behavior.

The problem I am facing is that the plot should be a near-straight line, whereas my plot is not.

What am I doing incorrectly?

- **With smooting**:

[image]

- **Without smoothing**:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Function to compute moving average
def moving_average(x, w):
    return np.convolve(x, np.ones(w), 'valid') / w

# Read data from file, skipping the first row (header)
data = np.loadtxt('cm.dat', skiprows=1)

# Wrap CM values if they exceed -1000 or +1000
data = np.mod(data + 1000, 2000) - 1000  # performs the wrap operation

# Initialize reference point
x0, y0, z0 = data[0]

# Compute squared displacement for each time step
SD = [(x - x0)**2 + (y - y0)**2 + (z - z0)**2 for x, y, z in data]

# Compute the cumulative average of SD to get MSD at each time step
MSD = np.cumsum(SD) / np.arange(1, len(SD) + 1)

# Size of the moving window for smoothing
window_size = 100

# Apply moving average smoothing to MSD
MSD_smoothed = moving_average(MSD, window_size)

# Generate time steps for smoothed MSD
t_smoothed = np.arange(window_size, len(MSD) + 1)

# Create a log-log plot of smoothed MSD versus t
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
plt.loglog(t_smoothed, MSD_smoothed, marker='o')
plt.title('Smoothed Mean Squared Displacement vs Time')
plt.xlabel('Time step')
plt.ylabel('Smoothed MSD')
plt.grid(True, which="both", ls="--")
plt.savefig('msd_plot_smoothed.png')
```

Answer (score 4):

I think that there is nothing wrong with your calculations

Normally, a given behavior is specified as a rule due to some physical meaning, but when you do the experiment, you always get deviations from the theoretical rule. These deviations can be determined by the fitting tool you used.

In this case, you can fit your data to a line (red line in the figure below) and see what the intercept and slope mean for your case. Or look for each region and figure out what is happening in each section (yellow lines).

[image]

Comment: The formula was incorrect. It should be MSD vs. Lagtime (`tau`), not MSD vs. time (`t`).

Comment: So, do you have a new result? New graphs?

Comment: Yes, I solved the problem myself.

Comment: Could you add an answer here? Maybe someone else can have the same issue in the future.